# Migrate fileserver user-profiles to OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, onedrive, userprofiles

I've been trying to get a migration started for out company. We are in the proces of saying goodbye to out local fileserver for user profiles and moving to OneDrive. Most of our users are already using OneDrive. However we have not created the folder redirection for them. They are still connected to the local fileserver profiles.

The issue that i am running into it that i cannot get the SharePoint Migration Tool of the Migration Manager to migrate data from a \server\profiles\username\ location to https://my-company.sharepoint.com/personal/username_companyname_nl

It keeps throwin the error as mentioned below:
*The site collection can't be created because the URL is already in use or an invalid URL.*

I did a CSV (correctly formatted) as well as a manual task, buth fail. However in another tenant (without chaning any settings) the tasks run just fine. Just to clarify, that tenant also has users with an active OneDrive profile.

I'm kinda lost here, maybe you have some suggestions?